# synthesis of free standing silicene

Tags: solid-state-physics, graphene, nanoscience

Unlike graphene which can be isolated from graphite via exfoliation, the same thing can't be done with silicene. Most of the papers I see usually involve synthesis of silicene on a metal substrate such as silver.

My question is, is it categorically impossible to produce free-standing silicene? Are there any methods of doing so (no matter how hard or complicate or unstable it is)?

Comment: You can not synthesize silicene by exfoliation because there exists no stable silikon analogue of graphite. You might still be able to synthesize free-standing silicene (for example) for example by dissolving the underluying metal although I don't know if it has been done. It is all pretty difficult since silicene is much less stable compared to graphene.

Comment: "You might still be able to synthesize free-standing silicene (for example) for example by dissolving the underluying metal" -- are there existing literature on this?

Comment: not that i know of. it was just speculation on my part.